# Animation 2 graphics - Matplotlib -Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create 2 horizontal stacked graphics with animation in Tkinter. I already created my 2 graphics with their information but it is plotting all the information in just one graphic. It is not split in each one. Below is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter
from matplotlib import animation
import random


fig1, b1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 0.5), dpi = 80)
b1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
def grafico_1 (i):


    global b1
    global nume
    global valu
    global fig1
    global y_fix
    global x

    x = []
    y_fix = []
    ws = ['WIRE']

    for valu in range (1, 6):
        nume = random.randint(1, 10)
        x.append(nume)
    #print(x)
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x[0]) < 3:
        y_fix.append(int(x[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b1 =plt.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x[0]) >= 3 and int(x[0]) < 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1 = plt.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1 = plt.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c in x[1:]:

        if int(c) < 3 :

            b1 = plt.barh(ws, int(c), color= 'green', left=y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)
            
        if int(c) > 3 and int(c) < 5:
        
            b1 = plt.barh(ws, int(c), color='yellow', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)

        if int(c) >= 5:
            b1 = plt.barh(ws, int(c), color='red', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)

    #print(y_fix)test
ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, grafico_1, interval = 3000)


fig2, b2 = plt.subplots(figsize= (7, 0.5), dpi = 80)
b2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
def grafico_2 (i2):


    global b2
    global nume2
    global valu2
    global fig2
    global y_fix2
    global x2

    x2 = []
    y_fix2 = []
    ws2 = ['line 2']

    for valu2 in range (1, 6):
        nume2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        x2.append(nume2)
    #print(f'Grafico 2 {x2}')
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x2[0]) < 3:
        y_fix2.append(int(x2[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b2 =plt.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x2[0]) >= 3 and int(x2[0]) < 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2 = plt.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x2[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2 = plt.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c2 in x2[1:]:

        if int(c2) < 3 :

            b2 = plt.barh(ws2, int(c2), color= 'green', left=y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)
            
        if int(c2) > 3 and int(c2) < 5:
        
            b2 = plt.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='yellow', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)

        if int(c2) >= 5:
            b2 = plt.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='red', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)

    #print(y_fix2)test
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2,grafico_2, interval = 3000, frames=100)



janela = tkinter.Tk()
janela.geometry('1000x1000')

#upper_grame = tkinter.Frame(janela)


canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, janela)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(x = 1, y= 1)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2,janela)
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(x= 150, y=150)



janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: fyi.  `tkinter` allows for `set()` and `get()` which enables coders to avoid using `global` which saves polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of already calling the `b1` and `b2` subplot instances, you are creating new plots in your `grafico_1` and `grafico_2` methods and storing them as new `b1` and `b2` variables. Hence, you are seeing every change in a single plot. Here's how you do it correctly:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import animation
import random

# Create the Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x100')

fig1, b1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 0.5), dpi = 80)
b1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

fig2, b2 = plt.subplots(figsize= (10, 0.5), dpi = 80)
b2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)


def grafico_1 (i):

    global b1
    global nume
    global valu
    global fig1
    global y_fix
    global x

    x = []
    y_fix = []
    ws = ['WIRE']

    for valu in range (1, 6):
        nume = random.randint(1, 10)
        x.append(nume)
    #print(x)
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x[0]) < 3:
        y_fix.append(int(x[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x[0]) >= 3 and int(x[0]) < 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c in x[1:]:

        if int(c) < 3 :

            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color= 'green', left=y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)
            
        if int(c) > 3 and int(c) < 5:
        
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color='yellow', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)

        if int(c) >= 5:
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color='red', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)


def grafico_2 (i2):


    global b2
    global nume2
    global valu2
    global fig2
    global y_fix2
    global x2

    x2 = []
    y_fix2 = []
    ws2 = ['line 2']

    for valu2 in range (1, 6):
        nume2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        x2.append(nume2)
    #print(f'Grafico 2 {x2}')
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x2[0]) < 3:
        y_fix2.append(int(x2[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x2[0]) >= 3 and int(x2[0]) < 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x2[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c2 in x2[1:]:

        if int(c2) < 3 :

            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color= 'green', left=y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)
            
        if int(c2) > 3 and int(c2) < 5:
        
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='yellow', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)

        if int(c2) >= 5:
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='red', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)
    # plt.show()

ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, grafico_1, interval = 3000, frames=100)
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, grafico_2, interval = 3000, frames=100)

# Embed the figures into Tkinter using FigureCanvasTkAgg
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root)
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: output-image]